# How to enable Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop

I can see that we can enable code analysis in Visual Studio Team Systems. But i am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Do we have any option to enable code analysis in this version or can we integrate any tools like FxCop and StyleCop with this version for validating the code.

I am expecting my code should analysied the moment i build my solution.

If somebody aware of this, please share me some solution for this.

Answer (score 13):

You can integrate FxCop via Commandline in the post-build event of the solution.

Download FxCop 1.36 and add following command into the post-build event:

```
"$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe" /c /p:"$(ProjectDir)\FxCop$(ConfigurationName).FxCop" /consolexsl:"$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\Xml\VSConsoleOutput.xsl"
```

Via consolexsl parameter the output is formatted so that the output is included into you VisualStudio builderrors and -warnings.

We have created a FxCop file that specifies the rules with FxCop-Gui. That file is loaded in the command.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [comparison chart](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products), built-in code analysis support gets checked starting in the Premium column.

Answer (score 4):

There was also StyleCop mentioned in the original question, let me answer that part: it can be integrated into build chain too as described in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/source-analysis-msbuild-integration.aspx?Redirected=true). Sure you have to adjust path and target mentioned in article with current path/version of StyleCop (it's `$(ProgramFiles)MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.Targets` now).

To make it work out of box (source control), I usually copy targets file, StyleCop binaries into some folder in SC (target file can be adjusted for that), and use relative paths to reference it. This allows to avoid creating any environmental variables, and project can be build immediately from SC on blank machine.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable Code Analysis manually. Follow the [link](http://www.iprogrammable.com/2011/06/15/visual-studio-2010-professional-and-hudson-jenkins-ci-and-fxcop/) here

Comment: Hi and congrats on your first upvoted answer. It would be better for everyone if you summarized the most important points of the linked page here, because pages in the internet have a tendency to disappear. This would also make your answer more substantial and help you get more upvotes.