# Recommended static program analysis tool for VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, static-analysis

What Static program analysis tool for Visual Studio 2010 professional related to framework 4 can you recommend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833608/how-to-enable-code-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010-professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2010 comes with Code Analysis built-in. This is essentially an integrated version of FxCop.

ReSharper also does its own static analysis and can find a number of bugs/inconsistencies/etc. in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Both free and from Microsoft:

- [StyleCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop)
- [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify if you are looking for .Net code analysis or C++ native analysis.

Following tools all work with .Net.

Visual Studio 2010 has built-in code analysis (in its Ultimate and Premium versions) which used to be distributed separately as [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) - it looks for API usage errors, security vulnerabilites etc.

[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (free) thoroughly analyses C# code for coding style errors.

[ReShaper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) also does fairly good job with reaal-time code analysis, but is not free (but not that expensive either).

[nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) has some amazing features (including custom SQL-like query language to run queries on .Net assemblies), but is rather expensive.

[Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) (free) analyses .Net code and generates use-cases for unit testing.